# Mathematica NetChain With Mixed Inputs (Numerical and Categorical)

Tags: tensors, machine-learning

I have been experimenting with Mathematica Tensor Flow (NetChain and NetTrain) and I would love to know if a simple step exists to present an input with a mixture of numerical and categorical variables.
For instance, among my predictors (inputs) I have marital status, which is a categorical variable, do I need to create dummy variables before presenting it to the NN is there a short-cut that I'm not aware of?  I'm aware of NetEncoder, and NetDecoder.

Any insight is well appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to correctly use `CatenateLayer`, here is an example:

```
NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[]}, {{NetPort["CategoricalInput"], NetPort["Input"]} -> 1},
 "Input" -> {10}, 
 "CategoricalInput" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", {True, False}, "UnitVector"}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank You! Now, how do I create a graph network from this:

Comment: This is what I tried, but failed NetGraph[<|"l1" -> CatenateLayer[], "l2" -> 20, "l3" -> Ramp, 
  "l4" -> 2, 
  "l5" -> SoftmaxLayer[]|>, , { {"l2" -> 
    "l3" -> "l4" -> "l5"}}, {{NetPort["CategoricalInput"], 
    NetPort["Input"]} -> "l1"}, "Input" -> 10, 
 "CategoricalInput" -> 
  NetEncoder[{"Class", {True, False}, "UnitVector"}],]

Comment: @user34018 Clean that up, why there two `,` and nested lists `{{`? `NetGraph[<|"l1" -> CatenateLayer[], "l2" -> 20, "l3" -> Ramp, 
  "l4" -> 2, 
  "l5" -> SoftmaxLayer[]|>, {"l2" -> 
   "l3" -> "l4" -> "l5", {NetPort["CategoricalInput"], 
     NetPort["Input"]} -> "l1"}, "Input" -> 10, 
 "CategoricalInput" -> 
  NetEncoder[{"Class", {True, False}, "UnitVector"}]]`

Comment: Here is a sample of my data  {{0, 0, 1, "MS_S2", "F"} -> "no", {0.5, 0, 1, "MS_S2", "M"} -> 
  "no", {0.5, 0.5, 1, "MS_S2", "M"} -> "no"}  but I get "Input spec of the form input -> output can only be used
on a network with a single input and a single output.

Comment: Here is the transformation to my dataset:  tData = Table[<|"Input" -> trainingData[[i, {7, 8, 9}]], 
   "MaritalStatus" -> trainingData[[i, 10]], 
   "Gender" -> trainingData[[i, 11]], 
   "Output" -> Last[trainingData[[i]]]|>, {i, Length[trainingData]}]

Answer (score 0):

To work one has to set the dataset as follows:

```
tData = Table[<|"Input" -> trainingData[[i, {7, 8, 9}]], 
   "MaritalStatus" -> trainingData[[i, 10]], 
   "Gender" -> trainingData[[i, 11]], 
   "Output" -> Last[trainingData[[i]]]|>, {i, Length[trainingData]}]
```

Meaning each variable has to match the name in the NetPort